# Why cant I register on https://console.ng.bluemix.net/registration/

Tags: ibm-cloud

I can see it firing off ajax requests but the page does nothing. All validation seems okay. This is not the first time ive tried and i have tried in firefox and chrome??

Please advise

Comment: There is a button for support at the bottom of the page, have you tried it?  What was their response?

Comment: Based on the title and the text, I am not sure whether you are a registered Bluemix user or not. Can you be specific about your issue? Are you trying to register as a new Bluemix user and encountering an issue? Or, are you a current Bluemix user and are having issues with a specific service? If so, which one? This information will help us help you.